# How can I add a loading gif to this script without making it 2 pages

Tags: php, loading

I have a simple php script that can take up to 15 seconds to complete.  I would like to add a loading gif and I prefer to keep it all on one page

I am a relative noob and I have a php script that performs multiple tasks based on a value that is passed to the script.  For example, on a certain form submit, a hidden value "task" with a value of 'getSegments' is passed, and here is some of the php from the getSegments task

```
if ($task == 'getSegments') {

include('include/pre.content.php');

$response = [];
exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs phantomjstest.js', $response);

$data = $response[19];

// code that parses $data and builds $output

echo $output;

include('include/post.content.php');

}
```

It can take up to 15 seconds from when the user submits the form until $response is returned and parsed.  What is the easiest/best way to add a "loading.gif" to display during this time?

I'd prefer to keep everything in this one php script, with the exception that I can add code to my css files as well as pre.content.php, which contains the opening tags up to and including the closing head tag, and post.content.php, which contains my footer, copyright, and closing body and html tags.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 01-22-2019

Per Eriks’ suggestions, I created the following phantomtest.php file to test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" name="viewport">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<img src="images/loading3.gif" id="loading-gif">

<script>
$('#loading-gif').hide();
// $('#task_start_butt').click(function()
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#loading-gif').show();
    $.ajax({url:”pathTo getSegments.php"}).done(function(data){
        $('#loading-gif').hide();
        // display the result here
        doSomethingOnComplete(data);
    });
});
</script>

<?php

function doSomethingOnComplete($response)
{
// do here your work
$data = $response[19];
echo "Data = $data";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

and getSegments.php

```
<?php

$response = [];
exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs phantomjstest.js', $response);
$data = $response[19];
echo $data;

?>
```

I changed Eriks’ line

```
$('#task_start_butt').click(function()
```

to

```
 $(document).ready(function()
```

because I want the script to start on page load, when the user comes from the form.  I *think* the script is functioning properly, because loading3.gif is shown for a varying amount of time within the expected range each time phantomtest.php runs, and then it is hidden when the getSegments.php called by ajax finishes (I think).  However, I have not been able to display the output from getSegments.php.

If anyone has a suggestion on how to accomplish this I’d be very appreciative.  Thanks.

---

I updated further and moved

```
function doSomethingOnComplete($response)
```

out of the php section and put it in the script section.  I am now able to output the number 11 with

```
document.write(5 + 6);
```

so now all I need is how to get the result from getSegments.php into phantomtest.php.

Comment: "I'd prefer to keep everything in this one php script"  Do you have a good reason for that?  And is "this one php script" the same file as the form being submitted?

Comment: Yes, it is the same file.  Rather than have a separate file for everything the site does, there is basically one script that handles every task, including form display, that a user can do on the site.

Comment: No offense, but that is actually rather horrible architecture.

Comment: So from a best practices approach, it is better to have a separate file for each task or form or whatever?

Comment: Check out MVC architecture

Comment: Thanks.  As this site is in development, I can easily chenge the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the task with ajax and use JS to show/hide the loading animation.

HTML/JS (assuming jQuery):

```
<a href="#" id="task_start_butt">Start the task</a>
<img src="loading.gif" id="loading-gif">
<script>
    $('#loading-gif').hide();
    $('#task_start_butt').click(function()
    {
       $('#loading-gif').show();
       $.ajax({url:"url to your php script"}).done(function(data){
          $('#loading-gif').hide();
          // display the result here
       });
    });
</script>
```

you also need to modify your php to return just the data you want to show.

Comment: Eriks... Thank you.  I will try this and see how it goes.  I'll let you know, but I am kinda slow on the uptake so it may be a while.

Comment: Update your post with more questions as you go. The community will help you!

Comment: Thanks... I have taken your suggestion and updated with another question above.  Your answer solved my original question.

Answer (score 0):

It works!!!

The php:

```
$response = [];
exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs phantomjstest.js', $response);
echo json_encode($response[19]);
```

The JS:

```
<img src="images/loading3.gif" id="loading-gif">

<script>
$('#loading-gif').hide();
//    $('#task_start_butt').click(function()
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loading-gif').show();
    $.ajax({url: "https://aajumpseat.com/dev/getSegments.php"}).done(function (data) {
        $('#loading-gif').hide();


// display the result here

        output = JSON.parse(data);
        document.write(output);

    });
});
```